# importance of difference of gaussian

Tags: sift

i did my project implementing sift on beagle board xM and came out of it OK....but for the presentation part,i still don't understand the reason why difference of Gaussian was considered in sift rather than opting LoG(laplacian of gaussian).can somebody please give me an answer which will greatly help my presentation

Comment: DoG is just a faster approximation to LoG! SURF even approximates DoG with integral images ...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, sorry for the long delay.

In a LoG operation, first we take an image and blur it a bit. Then the second order derivaties are found which is also known as laplacian. It locates the edges and corners which are used for finding keypoints. But the second order derivative is extremely sensitive to noise. The blur smoothes it out the noise and stabilizes the second order derivative.
The whole problem is computationally intensive.
Thus a small tweak is made in which blurred images are found out and the difference of the images is found out. This is approximately the same as LoG but is computationally simple.

Hope I explained the question in the best possible way.